# Слово "ейщё"

Tags: общие-вопросы

Хотелось бы узнать где часто употребляется слово"ейщё"(от слова "ещё") вплоть до написания.

Answer (score 1):

Да, а российские покорители виртуальных просторов, году этак в 2005-2006 пИсали так и "ищо", "исчо" "ещо", и тп.
Быть может не будем засорять наш и так (благодаря коммунистам и прочей нечисти) осквернённый и многострадальный язык?

Пояснение: это я к комментариям ответа выше.

Answer (score 0):

А что означает это слово? Я , честно говоря, не нашел это слово в интернете.Может, вы имели в виду "еще''?

Вы знаете, "написали" - это не значит, что это слово должно где-то встречаться. Видимо, человек написавший это слово был безграмотным. А может, это т.н. падоканский язык. Слышали о таком?

Я просто поражаюсь людям, которые намерено пишут безграмотно!На вопрос "Зачем это вам?", они отвечают: " Прикольно." Человек в здравом уме так писать не будет! Имею в виду падоканский язык.

Comment: слово ещё. но его написали как ейщё. причём это не описка а привычка от произношения как я думаю. причём связанная с определённым местом жительства. вот как раз его-то я и пытаюсь узнать.

Comment: Некоторые пишут "исчё"